# Decrement doesn't work with size()

Tags: apex

Why we always get an error like `Expression cannot be assigned` during deploying below code

```
Integer resultSize = result.size()--;
```

where result is a list but those one works fine

```
Integer resultSize = result.size(); 
        resultSize--;
```

or even

```
Integer resultSize = result.size() - 1;
```

works fine as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pre- and post- increment and decrement operators change the variable's value directly. Clearly, where that variable is a function, it is not possible to do this (what does it mean to increment or decrement a function?) - it isn't the result of invoking the function you are incrementing or decrementing, but the function call itself.

You should simply use:

```
Integer resultSize = result.size() - 1;
```

The alternatives you show make sense because you have copied the return value of the function into a local variable which you then decrement.